# Minimize function subject to inequality constraints using KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

Task:
$$f(x)=x_1^2-2x_2+x_3^2\to \min$$
$$x_1+x_3=1$$
$$2x_1+x_2-x_3\le 2$$
$$x_1\ge0$$
Wolfram Mathematica result: $x_1=0, x_2=3, x_3=1, F(x)=-5$.

GNU Octave result: $x_1=0, x_2=3, x_3=1, F(x)=-5$.

How can I get the same results using Karush-Kun-Takker conditions (by solving a system of equations)?

It is advisable to see a complete consistent solution.

Comment: You are Russian, right?

Comment: @rodrigo-de-azevedo yes...

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. "Karush-Kun-Takker" is a direct transliteration of Каруш-Кун-Таккер and $\to \min$ is the Russian way of minimizing. Perhaps Soviet way. I have met Poles who use that notation, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we make it easy for ourselves by inserting the constraint
$$ x_1 + x_3 = 1 \Rightarrow x_3 = 1 - x_1$$
into our function. Not only does this eliminate a constraint but also reduces the number of variables on which our function depends. The constrained problem is simplified to
$$
f(x) = x_1^2 - 2x_2 + (1 - x_1)^2 \rightarrow \min
$$
$$
\text{subject to} \quad \begin{aligned}
3x_1 + x_2 &\leq 3 \\
0 &\leq x_1
\end{aligned}
$$
For this problem we can define the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}(x_1, x_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2) = f(x) + \lambda_1(3x_1 + x_2 - 3) -\lambda_2x_1
$$
with the first order necessary KKT conditions
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} =  0 \\
\nabla_{\lambda} \mathcal{L} = 0.
\end{align}
$$
Written out these are stated as
$$
\begin{align}
2x_1 - 2(1-x_1) + 3\lambda_1 - \lambda_2 &= 0 \\
-2 + \lambda_1 &= 0\\
3x_1 + x_2 - 3 &= 0 \\
-x_1 &= 0
\end{align}
$$
or in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
2 \\
3 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{KKT}\label{kkt}
$$
We observe that inserting $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 3, \lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 4$ solves \eqref{kkt}.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!